# Whose responsibility is it to free sk_buff

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

While creating a netlink socket using `netlink_kernel_create()` a function pointer is passed as argument to this function which is called when a message is received on this socket. This call back function receives an `sk_buff` as parameter which contains the message received.

My question is that whose responsibility is it to free this `sk_buff`?

### Example Code

> #include <linux/module.h>
>   #include <net/sock.h>
>   #include <linux/netlink.h>
>   #include <linux/skbuff.h>
>
> #define NETLINK_USER 31
>
> struct sock *nl_sk = NULL;
>
> static void my_nl_recv_msg(struct sk_buff *skb)   {
>
> ```
> struct nlmsghdr *nlh;  
> int pid;  
>
> printk(KERN_INFO "Entering: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);  
>
> nlh=(struct nlmsghdr*)skb->data;  
> printk(KERN_INFO "Netlink received msg payload: %s\n",  
>     (char*)NLMSG_DATA(nlh));  
> pid = nlh->nlmsg_pid; /*pid of sending process */  
> NETLINK_CB(skb).dst_group = 0; /* not in mcast group */  
> NETLINK_CB(skb).pid = 0;      /* from kernel */  
> //printk("About to send msg bak:\n");  
> //netlink_unicast(nl_sk,skb,pid,MSG_DONTWAIT);
> ```
>
> }
>
> static int __init hello_init(void)  {
>
> ```
> printk("Entering: %s\n",__FUNCTION__);  
> nl_sk=netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, NETLINK_USER, 0,  
>         my_nl_recv_msg, NULL, THIS_MODULE);  
> if(!nl_sk)  
> {  
>     printk(KERN_ALERT "Error creating socket.\n");  
>     return -10;  
> }  
> return 0;
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`net/netlink/af_netlink.c`:`netlink_unicast_kernel`, the caller of your `my_nl_recv_msg` function will take care of freeing it.